# Limit depth of data returned

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to limit the depth of data returned from Firebase database?

For example, if I want to get some data from a parent object without waiting for all of its children & sub-children, can I specify that I only want x levels of objects?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase does not yet have this capability.

We do intend to add it, but don't have a timetable yet.

Comment: Not yet. We still do plan to add it though.

Comment: please consider adding this feature soon ... it would solve a lot of denormalisation nightmares and the need to synchronise duplicated data across the firebase.

Comment: We also need this feature. After over three yeas I guess it's no longer intended to be added? What a shame - we need it...

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a `shallow` option...

```
{
  "message": {
    "user": {
      "name": "Chris"
    },
    "body": "Hello!"
  }
}

// A request to /message.json?shallow=true
// would return the following:
{
  "user": true,
  "body": true
}

// A request to /message/body.json?shallow=true
// would simply return:
"Hello!"
```

**From**: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data